# How to scroll to a specific div without changing the url using angular + ui router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two panels, outbound flight and inbound flight. Once the user select the outbound and inbound flight it does a price check and shows it at the bottom of the two panels (the fare), its hidden initially.

I want to be able to scroll to the farePanel once the outbound and inbound is selected from the controller itself, i've tried using $anchorScroll but it appends the id #farePanel to the url.

additionally I'm using ui-router, if that helps.

Comment: Can you share your code and tell us what you ve tried

Comment: This may help you to achieve your goal http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/hzxNa/1/

Comment: @HassanTariq Its a matter of automatically scrolling down once Outbound and Inbound is selected. Would it help if I shared the UI? The code is pretty long. Also what i've tried is using $anchorScroll and $location.hash() to go to the div, but it works only once :/. The user should be able to select the outbound and inbound segments multiple times to check the fare. When this happens the page should just scroll down to review the fare segment.

Comment: @NiketanRaval unfortunately no, all my content is under one template and its a matter of automatically scrolling down to view the div for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all that you need is to doing with plain javascript. Call the window.scrollTo function after calculate the distance from the top of the window. You can see a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/scyrizales/vj44Lumv/

```
angular.module("test", [])
.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $timeout, $window) {
    $scope.showFare = false;
  $scope.process = function() {
    $scope.showFare = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      var element = $window.document.querySelector("#fare");
      var distance = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        $window.scrollTo(0, distance);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Cheers that worked! would you know a way to animate the scroll to make it smooth however...

Comment: I updated with the ease function to make it scroll smooth